# $E^{A\oplus B}(t,\infty) =E^{A}(t,\infty)+E^{B}(t,\infty) $?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $A,B\ge 0$ be unbounded closed self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$.
If the supports of $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal, do we have $E^{A+B}(t,\infty) =E^{A}(t,\infty)+E^{B}(t,\infty) $ for every $t>0$?
Here, $E$ is the spectral projection. One can regard it as  $E^{A\oplus B}(\varepsilon,\infty) =E^{A}(t,\infty)+E^{B}(t,\infty) $.

I can prove the case when $A,B$ are bounded by the definition of spectral projection. Now, I am learning unbounded operators. It seems to be different.

Comment: What's the support of an operator?

Comment: @Roland 1 minus the  projection  onto the kernel

Comment: $E^A[0,\infty)=I=E^B[0,\infty)$ violates the identity right away because $E^{A+B}[0,\infty)=I$.

Comment: @TrialAndError  No...  the supports of $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal

Comment: Doesn't matter: the total mass of a spectral measure must be $I$, not $2I$.

Comment: @TrialAndError  here, it is $(t,\infty)$, not $[t,\infty)$. If it is $[0,\infty)$, of course it is $I$. However, $E^{A}(0,\infty)$ is just the support of $A$! We have $E^{A}(0,\infty) \perp E^{A}(0,\infty)$

Comment: sorry, $E^A(0,\infty)\perp E^B(0,\infty)$  
 
 
@TrialAndError

Comment: Can't happen. $E^A(0,\infty)=I$ and $E^{B}(0,\infty)=I$ if the spectrum of both operators is in $(0,\infty)$. So the sum of those two cannot be $I$, which keeps it from equaling $E^{A+B}(0,\infty)=I$.

Comment: @TrialAndError  Let $P$ and $Q$ be two projections with $P\perp Q$. Consider a positive operator $X\ge 0$. Then $E^{PXP}(0,\infty) \le P$ and  $E^{QXQ}(0,\infty) \le Q$. Here, at least one of $P,Q$ is not $I$.   Even if the spectrum is in $(0,\infty)$, it doesn't mean $E^{A}(0,\infty) =I$.

Comment: Every spectral measure associated with a selfadjoint operator on a Hilbert space has total mass $E(\sigma(A))=I$. Otherwise you don't get $f(A)=\int f(\lambda)dE(\lambda)$. In particular, $1(A) = I$.

Comment: However, in the assumption, we exclude $0$. Let's see ;  consider $\ell^2(N)$, $A=(1,2,0,\cdots)$ and $B=(0,0,1,2,0,0,\cdots)$. Then, one can see that $E^A(0,\infty)$ is the projection onto the space generated by $e_1$ and $e_2$; and $E^B(0,\infty)$ is the projection onto the space generated by $e_3$ and $e_4$.  I understand that  the total mass is $I$, but I just ask $E^A(0,\infty)$ and $E^B(0,\infty)$, which is not the total mass in this case. @TrialAndError   BTW, thanks for discussing